# Why gcc 9.5.0 treates x>x+1 as tautology?

Tags: optimization, integer, overflow, gcc5, gcc9

gcc 9.5.0 treates x<x+1 as tautology for "int x".

For the following program, gcc 9.5.0 compiler seems to replaces x<x+1 with 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 0x7FFFFFFF
int main() {
    int x = M;
    printf("%d\n", x<x+1);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", x+1);
}
```

So, the output of the program is

1
2147483647
-2147483648

It was not the case with gcc 5.4.0.
gcc 5.4.0 prints 0 as the first output.

- Why gcc9.5.0 treats x<x+1 always true?
- Can I disable the replacement?

(For "unsigned x", gcc9.5.0 does not treate x<x+1 as tautology.)

Comment: AFAIK signed int overflows are *undefined behaviour*. If you have an UB in your program, then the compiler is free to optimize it as it want and it can also crash. As a result `x<x+1` is always true. This is an optimization so previous compiler versions certainly did not include it and this is just an improvement over time. Disabling such a behaviour is not a good idea if even possible. Programs having UBs are ill-formed and they *must be fixed*.